# CI/CD with laravel sail test before deploy

Tags: laravel, docker, gitlab

I am newbie with CI/CD.
I working with Laravel Sail build with docker.
I try make a CI make a test before deploy following:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test-development:
  stage: test
  environment:
    name: Development
  only:
    - main
  before_script:
    - echo "Start testing..."
  script:
    - cd ~/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
    - git pull
    - if [ ! -f .env.testing ]; then cp .env.testing.example .env.testing; fi
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan config:cache
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan test --env=testing

development:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: Development
  when: on_success
  only:
    - main
  dependencies:
    - test-development
  before_script:
    - echo "Start deploying..."
  script:
    - cd ~/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
    - if [ ! -f .env ]; then cp .env.example .env; fi
    - ./vendor/bin/sail npm install
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate
    - ./vendor/bin/sail npm run build
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan config:cache
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan config:cache
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan route:cache
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan view:cache
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan optimize
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan queue:restart
    - ./vendor/bin/sail artisan storage:link
```

But when run it, I got error like:

```
Tests:    8 passed (8 assertions)
  Duration: 7.06s
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I got that error without any test issue but the deploy not run
What am I wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't use Sail in your testing environment.

Comment: it should be phpunit, isn't it?

Comment: Using sail, you are effectively using Docker in Docker, which generally speaking is quite tricky. Use the `artisan test` for your CI.

Comment: I dont understand your mean. Could you please explain more? - You mean I just can run the artisan test by manual or maybe `php artisan test` with my CI?
I try trace log when my CI running, I see the cmd try delete file *.tmp outsite my root folder, but seems he have not permission for that, is that reason?

Comment: Don't run Docker inside of Docker, if you aren't absolutely sure what you're doing. You need to set up your CI pipeline to **not** use any of the sail commands at all. You should exchange all your `./vendor/bin/sail artisan` to simply `php sail`